# Trying java client for secure connection with Kerberose on CDP 7.1

Tags: hadoop, hbase, kerberos

Trying java client for secure connection with Kerberose on CDP 7.1 but it is failing to connect.
can someone one help with this error.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Found no valid authentication method from options
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.IPCUtil.toIOE(IPCUtil.java:154)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Found no valid authentication method from options
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcConnection.<init>(RpcConnection.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcConnection.<init>(NettyRpcConnection.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcClient.createConnection(NettyRpcClient.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcClient.createConnection(NettyRpcClient.java:40)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.getConnection(AbstractRpcClient.java:350)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:419)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your question on SO. It would assist the community in answering your question if you posted the code sample of your configuration, setup (dependencies), and the code that created the runtime exception.

Comment: String principalName = System.getenv(PRINCIPAL_NAME);
  String keytabPath = System.getenv(KEYTAB_FILE_PATH);

  if (!isEmpty(principalName) && !isEmpty(keytabPath)) {
   UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
   UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(principalName, keytabPath);

   conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
   conf.set("hbase.security.authentication", "kerberos");
   conf.set("client.kerberos.keytab", keytabPath);
   conf.set("hbase.rpc.engine", "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.SecureRpcEngine");